# jquery onchange with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I am new to coding in php. Please help me with this. This is my html code.

```
<label>Select room type:</label>
<select name="user" id="user ">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
<div id="display"></div>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user").change(function (e) {
      var user = $(this).val();
      $.post("fetch.php",{"user": user},function (data) {
          $('#display').html(data);
      });
    }); 
});
```

This is fetch.php:

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['user'];
?>
```

Error i am getting when i run fetch.php is

```
Notice: Undefined index: user on line 2
```

Please help me where i am going wrong

Comment: Is that the response when you run it via your jQuery post? Or is that when you try and run it directly? (It WOULD do that if you just tried to run it directly, because nothing is $_POSTed to it).

Comment: `id="user "` that's the problem here. Remove the space. `id="user"`

Comment: i tried both with and without jquery post. It says undefined index. Why isnt posting?

Comment: i tried with removing space. didnt work

Comment: make sure you did load the jQuery library also and a proper doctype declaration.

Comment: `Error i am getting when i run fetch.php` Are you running fetch.php standalone? @varuni?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No buddy, this is something else. Check my above comment.

Comment: @PraveenKumar that makes sense also. Yet, their id (the way it is now), will need to have the space removed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That won't change anything buddy. Browsers are intelligent to trim off spaces.

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['user'])){...}` and use form tags.

Comment: you don't need to run fetch.php directly

Comment: yes i have used proper js file @Fred-ii-

Comment: @PraveenKumar Kumar yes i ran both,actual file and tried fetch.php also.

Comment: @varuni You shouldn't run the PHP file directly as it expects the POST value.

Comment: @Fred-ii- is form tag really necessary? coz i just want to run onchange event and i am not submitting anything

Comment: @PraveenKumar alright. Then what is wrong with the code above?? I am not getting expected output though

Comment: @varuni Do this. Check your Network Tab and see what's happening there? F12.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ;) ok i want something like if i change one value from one select dropdown i want the other dropdowns to load automatically (obviously from db). So i want to make sure value will be posted first without any error

Comment: someone gave you an answer now. But it's been downvoted (not by me). I'm sure someone else will be posting another shortly. I for one, would need to test this before submitting an answer/solution.

Comment: Something other than this snippet of code must be calling `fetch.php`.

Comment: @Barmar I believe you are right, because I just tested their code and it worked.

Comment: I have a feeling that your entire code is inside the same file, am I right? or as @Barmar stated, something else is calling that; an include maybe? hard to say here. There's something you're not telling/showing us. That space though, IS an issue in the ID.

Comment: @PraveenKumar *"That won't change anything buddy. Browsers are intelligent to trim off spaces"* -  I tested the OP's code and it worked ONLY if the space in the id was removed. This tested on the latest version of FF. edit: 23 minutes ago as per this comment and OP says otherwise. *Rich*

Comment: @Fred-ii- is definitely right about the space (at least in FF and Chrome). Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3c7fdnn/)

Comment: Oops. I checked in Chrome. @Fred-ii-...

Comment: @PraveenKumar I should put in an answer with *"remove the space..."* - and *"you're not showing us full code..."* - and/or *"you're using this inside the same file..., but didn't tell us...* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative Way**

**jquery code:**

```
$('#user').change(function(){
    var user = $('#user').val();
    $.ajax({url:"fetch.php?user="+user,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $('#display').html(result);
    }});
});
```

**fetch.php**

```
<?php echo $_GET['user'];?>
```

Comment: I Know Mr Fred & Mr Burmar Will Come To Give Comment. *Why This Code Will Work?* He He ;) **Merry Christmas Brother**

Comment: Glad It Worked. *Merry Christmas* @varuni And All Stack User's.

Comment: sorry but I get to differ. I tested the OP's code with no issues (aside my removing the space in the id). They failed to show us their real code and how it was used.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you also ;-)

Comment: `cache:false` what I believe happened here, is that it a cache issue and OP's PC had that file in memory, keeping the space in the id. That's why this worked. I had to make a point about it, as I feel that's what the real problem was. I'm not trying to rain on your parade or burst your balloon, but that's what I think happened. Everything's good here, OP can now stop worrying about their code and head off to the North Pole and see Santa. Santa like bourbon to keep him warm, so he'd better bring a few bottles ;-)

Comment: After seeing your comment , i can't stop laughing. Live Long @Fred-ii-. Lot Of Blessings From My Side. God Bless You Brother. Bbye. See You Next Year. :D

Comment: @NanaPartykar hehe, glad to see I made someone laugh ;-) all the best to you also, *cheers*